# Asp.net code first many to one

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

Well it's a noob question but i can't figure out the solution.
I have two entities, user and team. User can create a team and invite other users.  User can belong only one team but team has multiple users.
What would be the most correct relationship between users and team?  I also need DateJoin  in team and other properties. Should i  create third table(TeamMembers)?
Here is code what i tried :

```
    public class TeamMember
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Team")]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        public Team Team { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateJoin { get; set; }

        public RoleEnum  MemberRole { get; set; }
    }

    public enum RoleEnum
    {
        Capitan = 1,
        Main,
        Sub
    }
```

And team has list of members:

```
    public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }

        public ICollection <TeamMember> Members { get; set; }

    }
```

But third table means many to many relationship...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user can only belong to one team  then this is the correct format.

However, if you think you might change this policy in the future then I do suggest you use a many to many relationship. This would also allow you to keep track of the previous teams your users belonged to, by simply using a "DateLeave" property for example.

Comment: And what id should user has?

Comment: TeamMember Id? or Team id?

Comment: DateLeave nice advise

Comment: Oh wait in your example you already use a third table... This would mean a many to many relationship. You could also simply move the properties  `TeamId`and `DateJoin`to the user table and remov the  TeamMember table all together. But if you wish to have the log possibility I suggest  keeping the thierd table and adding a new property with *`"DateLeave"*

Comment: Yeah i would use third table , for history. It also bad that user table has so many properties.  Better to use many to many